# Google Analytics not including event properties in custom events

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have three GA4 projects setup for three separate websites. They all have been working for a few months, connecting the preset events. Earlier this week I added a custom event for thumbs up/down feedback. I copied and pasted the code for all three apps so I know it's the same. However, I'm only actually able to see the event properties in one of my apps (also happens to be the first one I tried sending events to). Is there any reason this could occur? I'm totally stumped at the moment.

Here is my code to send events:

```js
window.gtag("event", `${feedbackEnv}_${feedback}`, {});
```

I left the properties section blank because I only care about the default properties they include (`page_location`). However when I click on the button which sends one of these events, I see the event popup in my realtime dashboard, but there are zero properties when I click on it.